# Recurly subscription object not found

Tags: php, recurly

I have a form where the user can enter their credit information. When they submit I keep getting 'Object not found'.

I checked the keys and subdomain everything is correct. What could be the issue?

```
public function createSubscription($plan,$token,$email,$fname,$lname,$currency,$starts_at,$company_name)
{

    try {

        $subscription = new \Recurly_Subscription();
        $subscription->plan_code = $plan;
        $subscription->currency = $currency;
        $subscription->starts_at = $starts_at;

        $account = new \Recurly_Account();
        $account->account_code = $email;
        $account->first_name = $fname;
        $account->last_name = $lname;
        $account->email = $email;
        $account->company_name = $company_name;

        $billing_info = new \Recurly_BillingInfo();
        $billing_info->token_id = $token;

        $account->billing_info = $billing_info;
        $subscription->account = $account;
        $subscription->create();
    }
    catch (\Recurly_ValidationError $e){
        throw new CreditDeclined($e->getMessage());
    }
    catch ( \Exception $e) {
        throw new InvalidGeneral($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Now post your full error messages!

Comment: That is my full error message.. all it says is 'object not found' I am using the recurly php api client.

Comment: Try getting rid of the `catch` statements so the full exceptions can be thrown with stack trace

Comment: Doesn't look like I can remove the catch. I get error that I cannot use try without catch.

Comment: if you want to contact [Recurly Support](http://support.recurly.com) directly with your account information we can take a look at our logs and help out with this :)

Comment: remove the try and catch blocks. you should get an error message and stack trace that way.

Answer (score 1):

The two things I'd check first are that the plan code and billing token are valid.

The other thing to check is that you've loaded our PHP libraries. You need to have this someplace in your code:

```
require_once('lib/recurly.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Require the `lib/recurly.php` script and setup your authentication credentials:

```
<?php
require_once('lib/recurly.php');
// Required for the API
Recurly_Client::$subdomain = 'your-subdomain';
Recurly_Client::$apiKey = 'abcdef01234567890abcdef01234567890';
?>
```

It should be correct.Please re-check.